# Why sometimes I received some random data from serial port? using c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

Data supposed to be received should be something like"-31.12345 167.12345", but sometimes I received data like "2.378999E11 3.593719E"? I have checked my port setting they are using same parameter. My code as following:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte rxChar=0;
        byte[] rxDataBuffer = new byte[240];
        int rxdata = 0;

        rxNumberDataBytes = (byte)serialPort.BytesToRead;
        //SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        //rxdata = sp.Read(rxDataBuffer, 0, 8);
        while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            rxChar = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();  // read data
            // to display bytes received in hex,check was all data received
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                textBox3.Text += " " + rxChar.ToString("X") + "\r\n";
            }));
            switch (rxState)
            {
                case RxIdleState:
                    if (rxChar == 0x5A)
                    {
                        rxState = RxInstructionState;
                    }
                    break;

                case RxInstructionState:
                    rxInstruction = rxChar;
                    rxState = RxNumberofbytesState;
                    break;

                case RxNumberofbytesState:
                    rxChar = rxNumberDataBytes;
                    rxState = RxDataState;
                    rxdata = 0;
                    break;

                case RxDataState:
                    //  count number of rxdata until 8 bytes real data 
                    rxDataBuffer[rxdata] = rxChar;
                    rxdata++;        
                    if (rxdata == 8)
                    {
                        float f11 = BitConverter.ToSingle(rxDataBuffer, 0);
                        float f22 = BitConverter.ToSingle(rxDataBuffer, 4);
                        Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            textBox3.Text += f11.ToString() + "    " + f22.ToString() + "\r\n";
                        }));
                        rxState = RxStopState;
                    }
                    break;

                case RxStopState:
                        if (rxChar == 0x2C)
                        {
                            rxState = RxIdleState;
                        }
                    break;

                default:
                    rxState = RxIdleState;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A little more error handling code might help with testing, e.g. an `else` clause in the `RxStopState` to handle unexpected characters rather than ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're grabbing wrong data due to a wrong set operation.

In the following, you are setting the number of bytes you want and then setting the `rxChar` to the first available byte in the stream. That seems fine.

```
    rxNumberDataBytes = (byte)serialPort.BytesToRead;
    while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        rxChar = (byte)serialPort.ReadByte();  // read data
        ....
    }
```

However, in the following, you are then ignoring that `rxChar` value and setting it to the number of bytes that were available for reading.

```
case RxNumberofbytesState:
     rxChar = rxNumberDataBytes;  // <--- This is correct?
     rxState = RxDataState;
     rxdata = 0;
     break;
```

You are then using the new `rxChar` value to add to your `rxDataBuffer` instead of the first byte that was available in the serial port.

Looking at the flow of the code, the rest of the 7 bytes look like they will be correct, but the first one will always be wrong.

---

**May also just be floating point precision issue  ;)**